# In a postgresql select, add a timestamp column to an additional_days column

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

In one column I have a create_dtm saved as timestamp in postgresql.  Another column is integer wait_days.  When I pull a row from the database I want to retrieve create_dtm + wait_days as a timestamp.

It seems I should be able to do this...will I have to do it in my application code?

My non-working sample looks like:

```
select name, title, create_dtm + wait_days
```

Comment: Is wait_days a string? If it is, you need to convert it to integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add integers to a `date` but not to a `timestamp`.

You can only add an `interval` to a timestamp value, so you need to "convert" the integer value to an interval of 1 day:

```
select name, title, create_dtm + interval '1' day * wait_days
from the_table;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/891f5/1

(The next time, please post the error message you get)

Answer (score 0):

If `wait_days` is of `text` or `char` type, it will not work. You need to convert it to `integer`, then this query should be ok:

```
select name, title, create_dtm + wait_days::integer
```