# How to add a number from a column to a date in postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am trying to do something like this

```
select myDate+addDays from myTable
```

myDate is a datetime column in the table
addDays is an integer column in the table

Comment: what kind of result do you expect?

Comment: select  current_timestamp + interval '1' day * add_days_count from myTable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414919

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656182

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a postgresql select, add a timestamp column to an additional\_days column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414919/in-a-postgresql-select-add-a-timestamp-column-to-an-additional-days-column)

Answer (score 2):

```
select myDate + (interval '1' day * addDays) from myTable
```

Above query will work on PostgreSQL as well as Oracle.